# evolution error: mbox sent folder invalid URI

Tags: 11.10, evolution, mbox, maildir

My dad has a POP email account, and has been using Evolution to manage it since Karmic or Lucid (with no problems). After upgrading him to Oneiric a couple days ago, when I opened evolution, it asked to convert his mailbox format because the format had changed. (I think it wanted to switch from mbox to MailDir, but I can't remember.) I allowed it to convert—that was my only option—but now whenever he sends mail he gets this popup (screenshot at end of post):

> **Your message was sent, but an error occured during post-processing.**
>
> The reported error was "Failed to append to mbox:///home/shopmaster/.local/share/evolution/mail/local#Sent:
>   Invalid folder URI 'mbox:///home/shopmaster/.local/share/evolution/mail/local#Sent'
>   Appending to local 'Sent' folder instead.".

The `ls` listing at /home/shopmaster/.local/share/evolution/mail is:

```
1260822881.20004.1@shopmaster-laptop
local
local_mbox
pop
vfolder
```

[Launchpad bug #850106](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution/+bug/850106) also deals with this issue, but I thought Ask Ubuntu might be a good place to get answers as well.

[image: Screenshot of error message]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out:

> If the error message "Your message was sent, but an error occurred
>   during post-processing. The reported error was "Failed to append to
>   mbox:///home/user/.local/share/evolution/mail/local#Sent: Cannot get
>   folder 'Sent': folder does not exist. Appending to local 'Sent' folder
>   instead."." is shown, you can fix the problem by editing your default
>   folder settings:
>
> Edit > Preferences > Mail Accounts > Edit > Defaults > Folder for sent
>   messages.
>
> This bug is fixed in Evolution versions higher than 3.0.2 (stable
>   s> eries) and 3.1.3 (unstable development series). If this is not the
>   case, please add a comment to the corresponding bug report.

Basically says to edit the mail account / default tab and setup the sent (and probably drafts) folder location.

- https://live.gnome.org/Evolution/FAQ#Error_message_.22Failed_to_append_to....22_after_sending_message

Comment: it occured again on 3.2.2