# Using evolution in Ubuntu comes up with this error  when I send mail

Tags: evolution

The reported error was

```
"Failed to append to mbox:///home/ralph/.local/share/evolution/mail/local#Sent: Invalid folder URI 'mbox:///home/ralph/.local/share/evolution/mail/local#Sent'
Appending to local 'Sent' folder instead.".
```

Comment: Does the mail get sent? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

What about clicking "Help" from the Evolution main menu? You would find http://library.gnome.org/users/evolution/3.2/mail-error-failed-to-append-to-sent-folder.html

Answer (score 0):

When sending a mail, Evolution tries to store a copy of the sent mail if configured such (which seems to be the default). For each account, you can define the folder where sent mails should be stored into. If an error occures causing Evolution to fail storing the copy, it falls back to store it into its default (local) "Sent" folder instead, so you do not simply lose it.

I'd recommend you check the settings of your mail account where you are facing this problem. To do so, in Evolution, go to the menu and open *Edit -> Preferences*. As it is the first entry, it should be automatically open the *Email Accounts* tab (if not, do so yourself). Mark the account in the main window, and press the *Edit* button to the right. The 4th tab (*Defaults*) in the window which now opens shows the folder configuration. Check the folder for sent messages here, and make sure it points to an existing folder.

Basically, this also is described on the question [evolution error: mbox sent folder invalid URI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67846/evolution-error-mbox-sent-folder-invalid-uri), as I just see now.